# In what cases can the result of SubscriptionClient.GetMessageAsync be null?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I'm using the Azure service bus broker with the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Nuget package version 3.4.4

When I call [`ReceiveAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_ReceiveAsync)on a `SubscriptionClient` that is connected to a subscription on which no messages are published, the returned task completes after a minute or so with a `null` result.

I expected the task never to complete with `null`

Under what conditions can the Task returned by this method complete with `null`?

Comment: There is no `GetMessageAsync`. You've linked to `ReceiveAsync`, which includes in its documentation section reasons why `null` may be returned. So its unclear what the question is here.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever I indeed meant `ReceiveAsync`, but I don't see anything about `null` in its documentation

Comment: Okay, I was slightly misreading the documentation too - its own documentation just says that it's an asynchronous receive. However, if you look at the documentation for `Receive`, it documents the circumstances when it can return `null`. So put 2+2 together...

Comment: ah, thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever ! I never expected the API to work that way!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a TimeSpan to `ReceiveAsync` to specify how long you would like to wait for a message. By default it probably is a minute.

So you could do something like this if you expect to receive at least one message every two weeks:

`client.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));`

Answer (score 0):

The API that you are using assumes that you want to poll Service Bus for messages; meaning that you will have to regularly make calls to the Service Bus endpoint in order to accept messages. When there are no messages, you will receive a null response. I would not recommend calling `client.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromDays(14)`, because that will leave a single request open for that amount of time. Instead, a null result is the expected behavior, and you should call `ReceiveAsync` in a continuous loop.

However, there is also an API that will do this loop for you: `OnMessage`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_OnMessageAsync_System_Func_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__

Just make sure that the main thread of your program does not exit.